# Get datetime format

Tags: sql

How can I get a datetime from this date format: Monday_09_25. I want to remove the DAY and just be left with clean DATETIME

Comment: In what database system? PostgreSQL? Oracle? MySQL? ?? Handling dates differ between RDBMSes.

Comment: And from which year should this date be? Can't be this year, so probably 2017? Good luck.

Comment: And do you assume the date is for the current year?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a string manipulation assistance? The example you gave, you want to change the string `Monday_09_25` to string `09_25`? Or do you actually want it to cast to a Date object?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the conversion on different RDBMS;

mysql 5.7

```
select STR_TO_DATE(
      concat_ws('_', 
         substr('Monday_09_25',
             length('Monday_09_25')-4,5),
                year(curdate())),
                    '%m_%d_%Y') as date;
result: 2018-09-25
```

oracle 11gR2

```
select to_date(
 substr('Monday_09_25',
     length('Monday_09_25')-4,5) ||
        '_' || extract(year from sysdate),
         'mm_dd_yyyy')
          as "date"
            from dual;
result: 2018-09-25T00:00:00Z
```

postgresql 9.3

```
select TO_DATE(
 concat_ws('_',
    substr('Monday_09_25',
     length('Monday_09_25')-4,5),
        date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)),
         'mm_dd_yyyy')
            as "date";
result: 2018-09-25
```

sqlite does not have date format

```
select 
 substr('Monday_09_25',
     length('Monday_09_25')-4,5) ||
        '_' || strftime('%Y','now')
          as "date";
result: 09_25_2018
```

sqlserver 2017

```
select cast(
     replace(concat_ws('_',
         substring('Monday_09_25',
             len('Monday_09_25')-4,5),
                YEAR(getdate())), 
                   '_', '/') as datetime)
          as "date";
result: 2018-09-25T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: `2018-09-25` is a tuesday :-)